# How to Intercept touch input on Windows 8

Tags: windows, input, touch, hook, intercept

I'm writing Windows 8 desktop app and would like it to pop up when user taps the screen with (for example) 4 fingers. I've found this question:

[How to detect tapping (touch input) globally instead of mouse clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297322/how-to-detect-tapping-touch-input-globally-instead-of-mouse-clicking/14304825#14304825)

the answer offers 3 solutions. The first one is not good for me since I'd like to write app that works on each Win8 tablet.

The second one (RegisterPointerInputTarget) works excellent (my app intercepts all possible touch input, even when the start panel is active or a metro app is running), but the Windows itself begins to lack some touch capabilities (e.g. I cannot scroll the start panel with my finger anymore). I've tried to inject the touch input back, but with no luck at all:

```
if (message >= 0x0241 && message <= 0x024F)
{
    DWORD pointerID = LOWORD (wParam);
    POINTER_TOUCH_INFO pti;

    GetPointerTouchInfo (pointerID, &pti);
    InjectTouchInput (1, &pti);
}
```

(and yes, I've called InitializeTouchInjection (10, 0x3); before) Also, I personally don't like this way since the docs say that just one window can register itself for the pointer input. So I don't want my app to occupy such a resource.

The third solution (hooks) works good, but I cannot intercept touch from a metro app or the start panel.

Does anyone know how to correctly intercept all the touch input on Windows 8? uiAccess=true is not a problem, since my app will be signed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, It'd be great if you could share it! I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, still no. Currently I'm using hooks, but (as I said before) I cannot intercept touch input from store applications. The same is true for Windows 10.

Comment: @YasharBahman, finally I've found a way how to achieve this - I'm using the HID input technique to get HID messages from the touchscreen digitizer and then parse them to count how many contact points are currently active. So I can run an action when this count reaches the predefined value.

Comment: interesting! Makes sense, but since you're using hid, I suppose that means you can get a copy of the input but can't "intercept" it,  right? I.e. There's no way to prevent that touch?

Comment: Yes, this method does not allow to prevent touch messages to reach the original app. But it's probably OK since usual applications does not do anything on 3 or more touch contacts.