# Windows 8 Getting Absolute X Y Coordinates of Touchscreen (regardless of window)

Tags: windows, winapi, touch, gesture, touchscreen

I've scowered MSDN/Google for the past few days and I've been unable to find the answer to this question.

I'm looking to get the X Y coordinates of a touch/multiple touches on a touchscreen device powered by Windows 8. There are tons of guides on how to add a touch handle to a specific window, but I would like to create an app that relies on touch input, regardless of which window/app is the one in focus/being touched.

Basically, I'm looking for the lowest level touch API out there. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just convert the touch message coordinates from client to screen coordinates. But there's something you still haven't explained: How do you intend to capture touch events for other windows?

Comment: That's my whole problem :) If I wanted screen coordinates of just a window, I'd be set! But I'm looking to get touch input, even when the window is minimized!

Comment: Before worrying about how to convert coordinates (ClientToScreen takes care of that) you should worry about getting the input first. This is like asking how to spend money you do not have.

Comment: I completely agree that's why there's no mention of "converting" in my question and it states "There are tons of guides on how to add a touch handle to a specific window, but I would like to create an app that relies on touch input, regardless of which window/app is the one in focus/being touched."

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking how to convert coordinates you already captured, not asking how to capture them in the first place. You should not be stealing input from other apps. How would you like it if somebody was stealing *your* input? (Imagine if two people did this.)

Comment: lol I'm not looking "steal" it away from the other app. I just want to know what it is. At some point, in the OS the driver reads data from the hardware (maybe in an array of points), then it will translate it into a message and send it to the appropriate app. If it is possible, I'd also like a copy of that array of coordinates (or whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks Raymond, that's a great a great post! Using the hooks looks like it's almost exactly what I want! Except the problem is exactly what you called out, it steals input away from other apps. This is not what I want to do at all. Apparently, it's possible to reinject input.  But according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503236/how-to-intercept-touch-input-on-windows-8?rq=1) that also has some problems with scrolling on the start screen. Do you know of a way to consume the hook without "stealing" the input from other windows?

Comment: This is not something the operating system is designed to let apps do. Installing a hook is already venturing into dangerous territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to use the "legacy" (Windows 7) API. With this, you receive the touch input as a [`WM_TOUCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341.aspx) message.

You use the lParam of that message in a call to [`GetTouchInputInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371582.aspx).

That returns an array of [`TOUCHINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317334.aspx) structures, each of which includes an `x` and `y` coordinate (which, in what seems like it may be a record for useless/illusory precision, is given to a precision of a one-hundredth of a pixel).

For new apps, Microsoft recommends using the Pointer Input API. With this, you'd receive [messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454903.aspx) like `WM_POINTERDOWN`, `WM_POINTERUP`, and `WM_POINTERUPDATE`. With these, the lParam of the message contains a single x/y point for the input. For more complete information about the location, you'd call [`GetPointerInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454885.aspx) to retrieve the coordinates of the input in [`POINTER_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454907.aspx) structures.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick answer Jerry! I tried looking into to WM_TOUCH. I'm looking to write an app, that can get the x/y coordinates of a touch, even when it is minimized. I could be wrong (actually I hope I am!) but from the looks of it, the WM_TOUCH message only fires when the touch occurs on the window itself.   If I'm wrong, then awesome! If I'm right, then maybe there's a way to circumvent the window?